# Can you play Half-Life 2 without Steam?

Tags: steam, half-life-2

Is there an alternative to Steam? I would like to play Half-Life 2 legally, but I am not willing to install Steam (again). I looked at Steam alternatives, but non of them are offering Half-Life 2. Will it be possible to install and play Half-Life 2 without Steam?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what *is* your objection to Steam? Especially since just about every single alternative I can think of off the top of my head is significantly worse...

Comment: @Shadur I assume he wished to go the DRM-less route, a-la GOG

Comment: Half-Life 2's release was sort of Valve's flagship title for helping to promote Steam in the first place. There was never a non-Steam version for PC.

Answer (score 14):

With Half-Life 2 being a game by Valve, and Steam being Valve's distribution platform, Half-Life 2 is only available via Steam. This will probably also be true for all Valve products released in the future.

You can, however, play the Xbox360/PS3 version of Half-Life 2 via [The Orange Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Orange_Box), if you have any of these platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @BlueRaja, early morning mis-types, I guess :P

Comment: s/via/with/ ... arm, I mean "is only available **with** Steam".

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you can launch Half-Life 2 without Steam (though you still have to download it through Steam, and so you still will need to install Steam to download Half-Life 2).

Navigate to the Half-Life 2 folder and run the following command:

```
hl2.exe -hushsteam
```

Congratulations, you have just launched Half-Life 2 DRM-free!

For Mac/Linux, launch with the same argument but with `hl2.sh` instead.